# setWidth(double) has protected access in Control

Tags: java, javafx

There is a `width` property under `Properties inherited from class javafx.scene.control.Control` here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html

Upon clickign the `width` property, you can see the following page:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Control.html#widthProperty

with the "See Also" option where `getWidth(), setWidth(double)` are listed:

I am trying to use `setWidth(double)` for my button but I get an error message in NetBeans that:

`setWidth(double) has protected access in Control`

I am using it like this in my code for my button:

```
public Button[] stop_QR;

stop_QR[i].setWidth(20);
```

I know it is declared as protected, but I don't understand why I can't use it? Please advise

Comment: This is likely by design to cep courage you to make use of properly layout managers (at a guess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is made protected to allow layout managers calculate the optimal bounds of the Node. The users are expected to use `setPrefWidth()`, `setMinWidth()` and `setMaxWidth()` methods to constrain preferred node size.

Answer (score 0):

Protected means a field or method can only be accessed by it's super and subclasses.

Comment: Also, it can be used through our the package, right?

Comment: No. If you have no access parameters then the field/method is *package-private* which means it can only be used in the package. If it's protected, it can only be accessed by classes in it's hierarchy.